# SQL optimazation

Tags: sql-server, sql-optimization

I am working on a database where a total of 788 data is currently stored and continuously increasing with time.

My code is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT R.remarks, R.payerId, R.payername, R.payeraddress, R.collectorName, R.serialno, OOI.phone_no, CR.cr_no, F.application_no, R.series, R.txndate, R.amount, T.toda_name, B.brand_name, M.motor_no, M.chassis_no, 
                         M.plate_no, F.date_issue, M.year_model, M.body_color, OOI.ice_person_name, OOI.ice_person_address, OOI.ice_person_contact_no, M.motor_id, F.franchise_id, LEFT(R.remarks, 4) AS franchise_no, SUBSTRING(R.remarks, 
                         CHARINDEX('|', R.remarks) + 1, LEN(R.remarks)) AS motor_noremarks
FROM            etracs_tayabas.dbo.Receipt AS R INNER JOIN
                         etracs_tayabas.dbo.ReceiptItem AS RI ON RI.parentid = R.objid INNER JOIN
                         etracs_tayabas.dbo.IncomeAccount AS IA ON IA.objid = RI.acctid LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.vfTA_tblMotor AS M ON M.motor_no = SUBSTRING(R.remarks, CHARINDEX('|', R.remarks) + 1, LEN(R.remarks)) LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.vfTA_tblOperatorOtherInfo AS OOI ON OOI.operator_id = R.payerId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.vfTA_tblCertificateOfRegistration AS CR ON CR.motor_id = M.motor_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.vfTA_tblFranchise AS F ON F.or_id = R.objid LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.vfTA_tblTODA AS T ON T.toda_id = M.toda_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.vfTA_tblReconciledTaxpayer AS RT ON RT.payer_id = R.payerId LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.vfTA_tblBrand AS B ON B.brand_id = M.brand_id
WHERE        (IA.objid = 'FTFA00000242') AND (F.franchise_id IS NULL) AND (R.voidId IS NULL) AND (R.remarks IS NOT NULL) AND (RT.rtp_id IS NULL)
```

Everytime I run this code, it always takes me up to 10 minutes long or more to load up all the values. I tried to make a SQL View of this same code but when I run it, the error `Execution Timeout` always shows.

I want to know:

1. What is the best optimization method for views and stored procedure?
2. How can I lessen the time it takes for the data to load given that it has 788 data and increasing over time?
3. How to prevent a lot of execution timeout to happen in SQL or even in a program?
4. Some sites that help teaches SQL optimization.

I am trying to learn optimization right now because I noticed that when I make a query, it usually takes a lot of time to load up and sometimes producing the error `'Execution Timeout'`

I am currently new with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "788 data"? 'Data' is not a unit. Do you mean rows? If so, in which table?

Comment: @HoneyBadger 788 rows showing from this query that takes 10 minutes and sometimes 15 minutes.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Add table and index definitions. Any explain plan?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Updated the tag. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0):

I think using DISTINCT against such many columns cost a lot. Is that really necessary for your query?

I also wondered the following part.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.vfTA_tblMotor AS M ON M.motor_no = SUBSTRING(R.remarks, CHARINDEX('|', R.remarks) + 1, LEN(R.remarks))
```

It means there's no way to use INDEX for this relationship. How about adding a column to table etracs_tayabas.dbo.Receipt where you store the substring result, and calculating it when a record is inserted/updated to the table. In this way, you can make INDEX for this relationship and can optimise that part of JOIN.

Comment: Yes. Because the code returns a lot of duplicate rows from the database.

Comment: If you can identify which columns have duplicates, then you can use "group by" for those specific columns. It'll make the process quicker.

Comment: but as I can see in the JOIN's in your query, they all seems to be using some kind of ID, except for the JOIN I pointed out above. If those are primary key in each table, it doesn't make sense why you get duplicates.  Why don't you firstly clarify which table/join is causing such duplicate data?

Comment: If you are getting duplicates then your join conditions may be incorrect. If your joins are incorrect, fixing them means you can remove the `distinct`, and you will likely get good performance increase

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Then I shall first see and check my codes above. Thanks

Comment: The first step to optimisation is understanding query plans and indexes.